# djnago View - how get a count queries from view?

Tags: python, django, django-views

how can I get the number of db requests during a view call?

```
connetction.queries
```

return empty list.

My views.py:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(OrderListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    date = Order.objects.get(number=1).created_date
    last_date = Order.objects.all().order_by('id').last()
    filter_ = Order.objects.filter(created_date__lte=date, created_date__gte=last_date.created_date)
    if self.request.GET:
        since_date = self.request.GET.get('date_since')
        to_date = self.request.GET.get('date_to')
        filter_ = filter_.filter(created_date__lte=since_date, created_date__gte=to_date)
    context['OrderListView'] = filter_
    context['connections'] = connection.queries
    return context
```

Comment: You can use `django-debug-toolbar` for that. Its the best tool and can do much more than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to install **django-debug-toolbar**.

[Here](https://medium.com/@ranjanmp/simple-guide-to-django-debug-toolbar-5bf112731631) is an article which guides you on how to set up the django-debug-toolbar.

You can also use django.db.connection to time and find the query count.

In your case, change

```py
context['connections'] = len(connection.queries)
```

**len(connection.queries)** returns the count of the queries.